# procmail: processing old mail

Tags: procmail

I finished tunning my .procmailrc, now I want to process all the mails I have in my Inbox. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The tool for doing this is `formail` which is part of procmail. You first move all the mail you want to process somewhere else to prevent infinite loops and then run `formail -s procmail < old_inbox` where `old_inbox` is what you renamed your mail file. This assumes your mailbox is a single file in mbox format.